# Ruby Beginner: Application returns error whether end statement is included or not

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to follow a Ruby tutorial, but I'm getting a situation where my code returns an error for my while block.

If I include 'end' at the end of my while block, like so:

```
while attempts < 3
    puts "Please input your username."
    usernameTest = gets.chomp
    puts "Please input your password."
    passwordTest = gets.chomp
    attempts++
end
```

It returns with `syntax error, unexpected` end'`.

However, if I remove that last `end` statement, it returns with `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input`.  So it seems to be unable to make up its mind whether it wants that `end` statement or not.

Comment: The problem is the `++`, in Ruby that operator doesn't exist. Use `attempts += 1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`attempts++` isn't valid in Ruby, you need to use `attempts += 1` instead

Comment: Actually `attempts++` is valid; it just do what was intended: `attemps = 0; attempts++ 1; attempts #=> 1`. Ruby treats `attempts++ 1` as `attempts + (+1)`.

Comment: er, doesn't do.